# Как вызвать асинхронный метод из Main?

Tags: c#, async-await

Работает ли данный код асинхронно? По идее, должен, но у меня почему-то основной поток блокируется.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DoSomething();
    Console.WriteLine("Now u can type something");
    Console.ReadLine();
}        

public static async void DoSomething()
{
    using (FilmContext context = new FilmContext())
    {
        var c = await (from b in context.Films select b).ToListAsync();

        foreach (var a in c)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(a.Descripton);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: потому что вызов `DoSomething();` - синхронный

Comment: @Igor Кажется, я не до конца понял, как асинхронно вызывать методы. Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: @Castiel_Luciefer2000: Я дополнил ответ, смотрите

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Смотрите.

Вы хотите, чтобы вывод в функции `Main` происходил после окончания `DoSomething`? Значит, вам нужно (асинхронно) дождаться окончания работы этой функции. Для этого нужны следующие изменения:

1. Функция должна возвращать не `void` (`async void` вообще нужен лишь в специфических случаях, т. к. его невозможно дождаться через `await`), а `Task`.
2. Вы должны в `Main` дождаться окончания `DoSomething`, используя `await DoSomething();`.
3. Чтобы в функции `Main` можно было использовать `await`, проще всего сделать её тоже асинхронной. В свежих версиях C# ([начиная с C# 7.1](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7-1)) это легко делается при помощи объявления `static async Task Main(string[] args)`.

Итого:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    await DoSomething();
    Console.WriteLine("Now u can type something");
    Console.ReadLine();
}        

public static async Task DoSomething()
{
    using (FilmContext context = new FilmContext())
    {
        var c = await (from b in context.Films select b).ToListAsync();

        foreach (var a in c)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(a.Descripton);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Если вам нужно, чтобы выполнение проходило параллельно, возникает вопрос, насколько дорого конструирование `FilmContext:`. Если этот код выполняется быстро, то ваш начальный код был верен, но лучше бы переписать его в таком виде:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var t = DoSomething();
    Console.WriteLine("Now u can type something");
    Console.ReadLine();
    if (!t.IsCompleted)
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting until task finishes...");
    await t;
}        

public static async Task DoSomething()
{
    using (FilmContext context = new FilmContext())
    {
        var c = await (from b in context.Films select b).ToListAsync();

        foreach (var a in c)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(a.Descripton);
        }
    }
}
```

Если же `new FilmContext` выполняется медленно, то проще всего выгрузить весь `DoSomething()` на пул потоков:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var t = Task.Run(DoSomething);
    Console.WriteLine("Now u can type something");
    Console.ReadLine();
    if (!t.IsCompleted)
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting until task finishes...");
    await t;
}
```

Comment: Вы вернулись? Рад, если так.

Comment: урааа, @VladD с нами! :)

Comment: @Castiel_Luciefer2000: Дополнил ответ, смотрите

Comment: И снова фирменное `Смотрите` в начале.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov: Стиль не пропьёшь :)

Comment: @VladD, А попытки были?

Comment: @Other: Постоянные!

Comment: @VladD Берёзовым или морковным соком пытались?

Comment: @VladD, а в чем смысл делать Main асинхронным в данном случае? Не проще ли через Wait дождаться? Ну т.е получить Task, а в нужно месте дождаться его.

Comment: @iluxa1810: `Wait` для тасков потенциально опасен и по-хорошему должен всегда вызывать повышенное внимание. С повсеместным `await` код выглядит безопаснее, что ли. Хотя да, в некоторых случаях заменить на `Wait` можно. Например, код из последнего примера мог бы зависнуть бы в WPF-программе, если заменить `await t` на `t.Wait()`, в случае если `DoSomething` пытается общаться с главным потоком. (Но в консольной программе вернуться в главный поток невозможно, так что всё в порядке.)